# MCAdvertiserAssistant doesn't alert host on connection request

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, swift5

I'm working with Swift 5 trying to connect devices with MultipeerConnectivity, but on mobile devices, including simulators, MCAdvertiserAssistant doesn't do its job; the host is not given the "Accept or Deny" alert once the peer tries connecting with the MCBrowser. When Mac Catalyst is the host, however, the alert shows up just fine. Here's the (relevant) code:

```
import MultipeerConnectivity

class Multipeer: UIViewController, MCSessionDelegate, MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate {
    var peerID: MCPeerID!
    var session: MCSession!
    var advertiserAssist: MCAdvertiserAssistant!
    public static var peerData: Data!
    public static var peerDataDecoded: Dictionary<String, Any>!
    public static var userData: Data! = CharacterCreate.userData
    public static var userDataDecoded: Dictionary<String, Any>!
    var currentlyHosting: Bool!
     
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        do {
            Multipeer.userDataDecoded = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Multipeer.userData, options: .mutableContainers) as? Dictionary<String, Any>
        }
        catch {
            Multipeer.userDataDecoded = ["Not Found": "Not Found"]
        }
        if Multipeer.userDataDecoded["charName"] as? String == "" {
            peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.current.name)
        }
        else {
            peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: Multipeer.userDataDecoded["charName"] as! String)
        }
        session = MCSession(peer: peerID, securityIdentity:  nil, encryptionPreference: .required)
        session.delegate = self
        currentlyHosting = false
        session.disconnect()
    }
    @IBAction func startPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if session.connectedPeers.count == 0 && !currentlyHosting {
            let startActionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Start Playing", message: "Would you like to host or join the game?", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
            startActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Host (DM)", style: .default, handler: {(action:UIAlertAction) in
                self.advertiserAssist = MCAdvertiserAssistant(serviceType: "connectRequest", discoveryInfo: nil, session: self.session)
                self.advertiserAssist.start()
                self.currentlyHosting = true
            }))
            startActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Join (Player)", style: .default, handler: {(action:UIAlertAction) in
                let browser = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType: "connectRequest", session: self.session)
                browser.delegate = self
                self.present(browser, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }))
            startActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            if let popoverPresentationController = startActionSheet.popoverPresentationController {
                popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view
                popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = (sender as AnyObject).bounds
            }
            self.present(startActionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else if session.connectedPeers.count == 0 && currentlyHosting {
            let waitActionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Searching...", message: "Waiting for players to join...", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
            waitActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Stop Connection", style: .destructive, handler: {(action) in
                self.session.disconnect()
                self.currentlyHosting = false
            }))
            waitActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            if let popoverPresentationController = waitActionSheet.popoverPresentationController {
                popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view
                popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = (sender as AnyObject).bounds
            }
            self.present(waitActionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            let disconnectActionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Disconnect?", message: "Are you sure you want to disconnect?", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
            disconnectActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Stop Connection", style: .destructive, handler: {(action) in
                self.session.disconnect()
                self.currentlyHosting = false
            }))
            disconnectActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            if let popoverPresentationController = disconnectActionSheet.popoverPresentationController {
                popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view
                popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = (sender as AnyObject).bounds
            }
            self.present(disconnectActionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive data: Data, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            Multipeer.peerData = data
            do {
                Multipeer.peerDataDecoded = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Multipeer.peerData, options: .mutableContainers) as? Dictionary<String, Any>
                print(Multipeer.peerDataDecoded!)
                self.present(CharacterRecieved(), animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            catch {
                Multipeer.peerDataDecoded = ["Not Found": "Not Found"]
            }
        }
    }
    func browserViewControllerDidFinish(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
        if !hosting {
            do {
                try session.send(Multipeer.userData, toPeers: session.connectedPeers, with: .reliable)
            }
            catch {
                print("Could not send data to peer")
            }
        }
        browserViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func browserViewControllerWasCancelled(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
        browserViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with the current version of iOS, or am I just doing something wrong? I've seen similar questions on different forums but none have answers.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the answer was to stop using the `MCAdvertiserAssistant` and use `MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser` instead.

I was helped by this post: [hackingwithswift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/books/project25-update-for-ios-13-4-1/1492)